# Speeding up Hausdorff in native python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, gpu, spatial

I have two Numpy arrays that describe a 3D model, each of shape `(471843, 3)`, where the '3' depicts spatial coordinate values, x,y and z and the '471843' are the vertices.
I am trying to calculate the Hausdorff distance between the two using the Hausdorff function from https://github.com/mavillan/py-hausdorff.

The function is executing but it does not seem to stop. It ran for almost 40 minutes and still didn't show any signs of stopping. Is this because it'll take a long time or some other reason? Also, from what I gather its a parallelizable function, so how can I export execution to CUDA GPUs to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"Is this because it'll take a long time or some other reason?"*

Test it!
Run the very same function on `( 1E1, 1E2, 1E3, 1E4 )` datapoints and you can easily derive your ETA for the `4.7E5` datapoints. That's fair, isn't it?

```
   from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch()

   SIZINGs = ( 1E1, 2E1, 5E1,
               1E2, 2E2, 5E2,
               1E3, 2E3, 5E3,
               1E4, 2E4, 5E4
               )
   MASK    = "INF: a problem-size {0:>5d} took {1:>12d} [us] to process"
   TIMINGs = {}

   #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   print(  80*"_" )
   for aSize in SIZINGs:
       aClk.start()
       _ = 3D_wrapper_for_HausdorfDistance( data     = DATA[:int(aSize),:],
                                            distance = aCustomHausdorfDistance_in3D
                                            )
       TIMINGs[aSize] = aClk.stop()
       print( MASK.format( aSize, TIMINGs[aSize] )
   print(  80*"_" )
   #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> **Q** : *"...how can I export execution to CUDA GPUs to speed up the process?"*

First solve IF it makes sense to design & execute a CUDA-kernel so as to be performance-wise meaningful to be used. If it shows, there will not be any chance to perform faster than in a native `N x 3+ [GHz]`-***LARGE-Cache*-device**, then and only then start the efforts to port the algorithm so as to efficiently harness the restricted precision contemporary GPU SMX SIMD-processors.